# Can I launch a virtualbox VM across the network?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, remote-execution

I'm trying to signal a VB virtual to spin up on a remote computer without having to remote into that host first (not trying to run a virtual across the lan, that sounds painful).  It seems needlessly tedious to RDP into the virtual host, start up the VMs, log out, then remote into the VMs.

My old desktop has become little other than a virtualbox host, and 90% of the time, I just turn it on and remote into its VMs.  I've created shortcuts to the VMs, but now I'd like to skip the extra step of remoting into that box to launch them.  I haven't looked into launching them on startup, because I need the first to launch fully before spinning up the 2nd.

I'm stumbling on trying to achieve this with psexec, but if there's a less kludgy way to do it (possibly with some new win7 toys I haven't used yet?), that would be sweet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can start up your machines from the command line with VBoxHeadless and they will run without a window. Then you can ssh into them or rdp into them or vnc or whatever you like.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the headless option, good stuff - now I need to figure out how to launch it without logging into the host.

Answer (score 1):

You could have look at [phpVirtualbox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/).

It does mean having a web server running on the VirtualBox host, though.

Comment: Nifty option, I'd like to avoid the overhead, but I may go that route if I can't fire them up without doing anything on the host.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more than what you want, but the default Virtualbox install comes with webserver which hosts their API via a SOAP web service.  The [Virtualbox SDK](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) has nice Object Oriented wrappers for the SOAP API written in Java, Python and PHP.  If you've got the programming know-how, you could write a simple client using one of the provided client libraries (or any other language that can talk SOAP) and just run the web-service server on the host.

Comment: That kind of coolness is why I love VirtualBox.  It's a sledgehammer to kill a fly in my case, but knowing what's out there is very good.  ;)